# find subtree by given trace Hakell

Tags: haskell

I am stock on this problem. 
The problem is Write a haskell function trace (including the type declaration line in your answer), which will
take a Path p and a BTree as input, returns the subtree that you arrive at by tracing the path in
tree.
Note that (trace p Empty) should always return Empty.
Here is my solution so far

```
data BTree a = Empty 
             | BNode a ( BTree a ) ( BTree a ) deriving (Show)
data Dir = Lft |Rght
type Path = [Dir]

tree = BNode 1 (  BNode 2 (BNode 4 (Empty) (Empty)) (BNode 5 (Empty) (Empty)) ) ( BNode 3 Empty Empty)

tree1 = BNode 1 (  BNode 2 (BNode 4 (Empty) (Empty)) (BNode 5 (Empty) (Empty)) ) (  BNode 2 (BNode 4 (Empty) (Empty)) (BNode 5 (BNode 3 Empty Empty) (Empty)) )

-- 1.
trace :: Path -> BTree a -> BTree a
trace  p Empty =  Empty 
trace [] a =  a 
trace  (x:xs) (BNode b left right) = if x == Lft then trace xs left else trace xs right
```

then i got

```
No instance for (Eq Dir) arising from a use of ‘==’

    • In the expression: x == Lft
      In the expression:
        if x == Lft then trace xs left else trace xs right
      In an equation for ‘trace’:
          trace (x : xs) (BNode b left right)
            = if x == Lft then trace xs left else trace xs right
   |
14 | trace  (x:xs) (BNode b left right) = if x == Lft then trace xs left else trace xs right
   |                                         ^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Operator `==` is a member of [type class `Eq`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-14.11/base-4.12.0.0/Prelude.html#t:Eq), so if you want to use operator `==` on your `Dir` type, you have to derive the `Eq` type class for it:

```
data Dir = Lft | Rght deriving Eq
```

However, a better way would be to use pattern matching instead of comparing with `==`:

```
trace  p Empty =  Empty 
trace [] a =  a 
trace (Lft:xs) (BNode _ left _) = trace xs left 
trace (Rght:xs) (BNode _ _ right) = trace xs right
```

Comment: Good answer, but it can be made a bit tidier by consolidating the last two cases to `trace (dir:dirs) (BNode x left right) = trace dirs $ case dir of {Lft -> left; Rght -> right}` (of course we'd use whitespace instead of braces in a real source file)

Comment: @amalloy I judged that to be way too advanced for an absolute novice

Comment: I think it's pretty close to what chen was trying to write already, but mistakenly using `if` instead of `case`.

Comment: @chenCrush if my answer helped you, would you consider accepting it? You can do that by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer.

Comment: Thanks again for helping me. I clicked the checkmark